# Selection change event for MFC CListCtrl, caused by mouse/keyboard input only

Tags: c++, mfc, listview

i am using an mfc ListCtrl, is there anyway to know if a selection change was caused by mouse/keyboard input rather than a programatic change? i am after the same behaviour as ON_LBN_SELCHANGE for a listbox. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301%28VS.85%29.aspx)() to find out whether a key or mouse button was pressed. Do not use [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28VS.85%29.aspx)() because that API will tell you the current state of the keyboard/mouse buttons, which may have changed when you handle the LBN_SELCHANGE message. GetKeyState() however will tell you the state as it was when LBN_SELCHANGE was generated.

Comment: Hi folks, welcome to 2022.  If you want to use this handy trick, be sure to check the state of the arrow keys (or whatever), rather than the mouse buttons.  On Windows 11 at least, `LBN_SELCHANGE` is only sent on a mouse **up**, so `GetKeyState` can't tell you anything useful.  Fortunately, I only want to differentiate between mouse event and keyboard events, so lucky me.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to find out this information.  You know if you are sending the message to the CListCtrl so you should set a flag if you do.  If the LBN_SELCHANGE message is received and the flag has NOT been set then it must have come from a keyboard/mouse.